# asmx service throwing error when deployed on .net framework 4.0

Tags: service, asmx

I have an asmx web service based on .net framework 3.5. I deployed it in the server and set the framework version for the app pool to 4.0 (Integrated). After making the change if I try to send a request to the service in xml format using soap client I am getting the error "Data Is Invalid at root line 1 position 1" if I change the runtime version of the app pool to 2.0 it works fine.I had it working fine on a 2003 server until now. could somebody please let me know what the issue could be with this?

I was able to narrowed down the issue to one point. The service that I have is an asmx service as said earlier, what I found out is that when changing the app pool to 4.0 and when I send a xml request to the service through soap client, I am getting the error Data at root level is Invalid at the while loop which is the given at the validating the request with a xsd. Please find the method below. the error is thrown exactly at the while loop. Not sure what the error is. Before this method is called the request is serialized u can find that code also below. Not sure if the error is happening during serialization or during validation, I mean, may be the request is not serialized properly, so the validation is failing, but not sure on this.

//Serialization

```
       XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(MyRequest.GetType()); //MyRequest is the input object.
       MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        UnicodeEncoding uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.Unicode);
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, MyRequest);
        int count = (int)memoryStream.Length;            
        byte[] requestArray = new byte[count];           
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        memoryStream.Read(requestArray, 0, count);
        string stringXML= uniEncoding.GetString(requestArray).Trim();

    public bool ValidateXML(string stringXML, Uri schemaURI)
    {
        XmlSchemaSet sc = null;
        XmlReaderSettings settings = null; 
        XmlReader reader = null;
        StringReader txtReader = null;

        try
        {
            // Create the XmlSchemaSet class.
            sc = new XmlSchemaSet();

            sc.Add(null, schemaURI.ToString());

            // Set the validation settings.
            settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            settings.Schemas = sc;

            txtReader = new StringReader(stringXML);          
            // Create the XmlReader object.
            reader = XmlReader.Create(txtReader, settings);                                                             
             while (reader.Read())
            {             
            }
            reader.Close();
            return true;
        }                       
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried building it with .NET 4.0?

Comment: yes,tried that too, but still the same error

Comment: Some more details of this issue are below.

Comment: Below what? I don't see any details.

Comment: sorry the comment din get added for some reason. I have added more details to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is not completely with the framework, it might be the classes that you use for serialization that's causing it.
replace the whole serialization code as below. this shud solve the issue.

```
XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject));
var subReq = new MyObject();
StringWriter sww = new StringWriter();
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww);
xsSubmit.Serialize(writer, subReq);
var xml = sww.ToString(); // Your xml
```